# Find all paths between rows in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I couldn't find the correct answer for my problem this is why I am asking.

I have a rooms table that have uid (integer, unique) column.
Also I have a exits table that has fromuid (integer) touid (integer)

I want to find all posible exits that leads from uid to target uid.

rooms table has about 32000 rows. each room can have about 10 exits that lead to other rooms.

What I want to get all possible rows that eventually reaches the target uid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it in Lua.

Create a Lua table that keeps the exits from each node as a table of node ids...

```
exits = {}

function dbexits(db)
    for fromuid, touid in db:urows('SELECT fromuid, touid from exits') do
        local et = exits[fromuid] or {}
        et[#et+1] = touid
        exits[fromuid] = et
    end
end
```

Use a breadth-first-search to see if there is a path from `fmid` to `toid`; the `seen` table prevents infinite regress on loops in the path.

```
function pathexists (fmid, toid)
    local seen = {}
    local work = {fmid}
    while #work > 0 do
        local c = work[#work]
        work[#work] =  nil
        seen[c] = true
        if c == toid then
            return true
        end
        for _,v in pairs(exits[c]) do
            if not seen[v] then work[#work+1] = v end
        end
    end
    return false
end
```

Use the `pathexists` function on each of the exits from the source node to see if it reaches the target node...

```
function findexits (sourceid, targetid)
    local result = {}
    local srcexits = exits[sourceid]
    for _,e in pairs(srcexits) do
        if pathexists(e,targetid) then
            result[#result+1] = e
        end
    end
    return result
end
```

Here is a simple test:

```
sqlite3 = require("lsqlite3")

db = sqlite3.open_memory()

db:exec[[ CREATE TABLE exits (fromuid, touid) ]]

db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (1, 2) ]]
db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (1, 3) ]]
db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (2, 1) ]]
db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (2, 3) ]]
db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (3, 1) ]]
db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (3, 5) ]]
db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (4, 2) ]]
db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (4, 6) ]]
db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (5, 1) ]]
db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (5, 2) ]]
db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (6, 7) ]]
db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (6, 3) ]]
db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (7, 4) ]]
db:exec[[ INSERT INTO exits VALUES (7, 3) ]]

--[[
for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM exits") do
  print(row.fromuid, row.touid)
end
]]--

dbexits(db)

--[[
function printf(s,...)
    return io.write(s:format(...))
end
for k,v in pairs(exits) do
    printf("\n%d: ", k)
    for _,e in pairs(v) do
        printf("%d ", e)
    end
end
]]--

e = findexits(1,5)

--[[
for _,v in pairs(e) do print(v) end
]]--

assert(e[1] == 2)
assert(e[2] == 3)

e = findexits(1,4)

assert(#e == 0)
```

The test passes using Lua 5.4 and lsqlite3 v3.24.0

Comment: Thank you for your hardwork this works like you said but I need to find the path between start room and the target room. in the exits table there should be a direction column. like fid = 1 dir = north toid=2

Comment: @Valour, surely you can have a table that associates roomID and exitID with direction; the algorithm doesn't need it, so it can be a post-processing step.